# How to ignore iPad auto correct recommendation?

Tags: ipad

iPad's typing auto correct sometimes can be useful, yet sometimes it provides the wrong recommendation. it's often inconvenient to break my hands from the typing position to tap the "x". I wonder aside from tapping the "x" next to the recommended word to ignore recommendation, what can I do on the keyboard to ignore it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a workaround, but what I always do is just delete the last letter and type it again. iOS recognizes this as an assertion that that's how you wanted to type the word, and won't give the suggestion again.

Also, if you type a word and it gets corrected, the erase it and type it again, it won't correct you twice.

Finally, it seems that if you type a word that isn't in the dictionary and ignore or erase the correction, it won't offer that correction again in that text field. You can try this by just typing the same "wrong" word a few times and it will stop correcting you.

It's not exactly what you're asking for, but I find the autocorrect to be sufficiently intuitive for me. (As a matter if fact, I typed this on my iPhone with absolutely no regard for errors.)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. There isn't really another way.

However, you can [manually add words](http://backstageav.com/help-files/2012/12/15/how-to-ios-keyboard-shortcuts) or phrases into the dictionary

> Go to the **Settings** app, choose **General**, **Keyboard**. Scroll to the bottom and you will see **Shortcuts**. At the very bottom you will see the ability to create a new shortcut.

When adding a word, you can add just the phrase and leave the shortcut blank if you just want to add it to the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I just learned that you don't have to be too accurate in hitting that x mark. Tap anywhere in the grey suggestion word box and it goes away.